# Java Difference between { Object a = new Object(); a.getVariable() } and { new Object().getVariable() }

Tags: java, class, oop, object, instantiation

i don't know if its asked before (i searched but couldn't find)

Is there any difference between the following 2 code blocks?

1:

```
// Let's say we want to get variable from non-static object
Object a = new Object();
int varWeWant = a.getVariable();
```

2:

```
int varWeWant = new Object().getVariable();
```

as you see second option is one-line code
and i know the java, both codes create object first and retrieve variable via method but i'm not java expert so i wonder if they have any differences ?

Sorry if it is silly question :D
i was just wondered this for too long

thanx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first creates an object that can be referred to later, then calls a method on it.

The second creates a temporary object that can only be used to call that single method.

Really, if you're using the second way, you should question if the object was necessary in the first place. It might make more sense to just make that method a standalone function unless you're using the Builder or similar pattern.

Comment: Yes, the second line absolutely makes no sense.

Comment: so temp object which is created in second option is garbage-collected by GC after statement and object which is created in first option stays after statement

Comment: @PunithRaj Unless, as I mentioned in the edit, the object is a Builder/Factory object. StringBuilders and similar classes will often be something like `new BuilderObj().addSomething().build();`

Comment: @sirmordred Well, you never know *exactly* when an object will be GC'd, but ya, I'd expect that the second one would probably be GC'd before the first.

Comment: @sirmordred The difference depends entirely on how big of scope those objects are being created in, how many other objects were created around the same time, when the last time the GC was run... The GC is difficult to predict without the use of external tools.

Answer (score 0):

both produce the same **BUT** option 2 is the object instance an anonymous reference... that means you can not do anything with that object after that statement...

Answer (score 0):

int x = new Object().getVariable(); 
This is done when the object have one time use.
Object a = new Object(); //Creates an object named a
This is done when object has multiple variables and functions. This way object is created only once and the variables and functions are called. If we were to use new Object().getSomeFunction() every time then new object is created every time. Its expensive memory wise and more lines has to be written.

Answer (score 0):

The result in `varWeWant` is the same.

Some minor differences:

- In the first version you can later use the Object for other purposes, as you stored a reference to it in the `a` variable (that's obvious).
- Introducing the variable `a` comsumes a small amount of memory.
- As long as the variable `a` refers to this Object, the garbage collector cannot reclaim its memory. (But compiler and runtime optimizations might be able to free the memory earlier, as soon as `a` is no longer used).
- Storing the reference in a variable will take a tiny amount of time.